# Loading XML "Cache" Versus Querying DB. The Drawbacks?

Tags: mysql, xml, orm, memcached, nosql

For a read-only application, I am currently storing data in a relational database, but rather than querying it via the app, I am doing a nightly write of the data, including its relationships, to an XML file.

Granted, it is not a a lot of data -- the XML represents less than 1000 objects.

Then, through client side code, I am loading that data, and "querying" it as necessary.

No write opertations are required -- the app's sole function is search and display.

I've developed the app in such a way that whether it queries the db or the loaded xml can be switched very easily, and so I am able to compare performance.

I find that e.g. full text search (as such) is instant, etc, with the loaded XML approach.

However, I know there are drawbacks to this approach, and I would greatly appreciate it if any of you could help me flesh out when and why this is or is not a valid approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of db, MySQL? Maybe for this case something much simpler will do, like SQLite?

Comment: I am using SQLite for development but had planned on MySQL in production. Maybe not necessary you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load `XML` into a good `XML` processing engine, it constructs appropriate data structures to speed up `XPath` queries or the tree traversal in general.

When you keep the data in a relational database and query it, the query optimizer builds a query plan which will access data in some optimized way too.

Which method best suits you completely depends on the nature of your queries.

Note that loading an `XML` document and parsing it on each client call may be quite expensive, and unless you use some kind of an application server which keeps the parsed `XML` tree in memory, a database query will most probably be a better way since with 1000 records your whole table will fit into the cache.

Comment: Thanks. Specifically, I am parsing the XML into strongly typed objects, inside the context of a Flex application. I have my own code for "querying" the objects -- mostly it is filtering an array, the array being the data provider for the search results view. In the last part of your answer, are you suggesting that, rather than writing to an XML file, I use cacheing and still load up everything on each client load, to achieve the same result? Can you expand a bit on "quite expensive?"

Comment: @moso11: `MySQL` cache is shared between the clients. This means that it stored all its data in `RAM` in a way which suits the relational queries. When you use a script language without an application server, the `XML` file would need to be read from the disk and parsed on each client request. This make take lots of `CPU` resources (depending on how complex your file is).

Comment: Ok, stick with me for a second. (=

If I want to avoid querying the DB for every search performed, I have a few options.

1) Write the XML File to disk, which is loaded only one time, when the app is first loaded. No subsequent loads.
2) Store that XML in the DB, turn on cacheing, and get the same result for my application's needs.
3) Run the complete SELECT query on the DB, also with cacheing on, to produce the XML file.

Assuming that any of these options strike you as valid, which one is best/why? Thanks again!

Comment: @moso11: just a second: are we talking about a web app?

Comment: @moso11: my point is that you should not avoid querying the DB for every search performed. `MySQL` has a query engine which filters and parses the data quite efficiently, and, given that all these data are cached (inside the `MySQL`'s own internal cache which is totally transparent to you), these queries can be very fast. This does not involve creating an `XML` file at all. If you still want to avoid DB queries completely at any cost (and pereat mundus), then option `1` is the best. I assume that "app is first loaded" implies you have an application server.

Comment: By application first loaded, what I should say is: Web Page First Loaded. 

The Website contains a Flex Application -- in the form of a Flash Movie (SWF).

The Flash Movie Loads the XML File each time the Web Page that contains it is loaded.

Your point that this is less efficient than running db queries is well taken.

Thanks again.

Comment: @moso11: sorry, I thought you were talking about the server-side application (i. e. scripts run inside an `HTTP` server engine or an application server). I don't know `Flex` internals, but I believe it cannot directly query a database server (and even if it could, it would not be a good idea to let it do it anyway). Since this application is run on the client side, `CPU` is not much of a concern. So option `1` would be the best way indeed.

Comment: Thanks. Flex can't directly talk to a db, it calls e.g. a Ruby or PHP or whatever script server side, and gets the results back. Same deal really as Ajax. And that's generally the way it would be done in a Flex app -- rather than loading an XML file as in Option 1. It's just that I'm finding with it being read-only, there seems to be no reason to run queries against the DB.

Comment: @moso11: you can make a server-side script then that returns the results of the query which will not have to be processed on `Flex` side. It will require more load on you web server's `CPU` but will save you the bandwidth. Don't know what is more important to you.

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this one. I probably will be doing what you suggest, as it is the common way to do it in a Flex app, but I am still curious -- I think I'll post a similar question with the Flex tag to see if others have run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds valid to me.

The drawbacks would come if the size of the data was prohibitively large and threatened your available memory, or if it was shared in such a way that thread safety was an issue.

But you say it's small and read-only, so it sounds fine to me.  Keeping the data close to where it's needed is something that every hardware designer would understand.

You say it's stored as XML, but I assume you read the file once per day, parse and store it in an in-memory DOM object, and query it using XPath.  Is the XPath performance adequate for your needs?  That would be my only concern.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, basically, though it is not JS but Flex/Actionscript. Please see my answer to Quassnoi with regard to the way the data is queried client side. I find it totally adequate -- surprisingly so.

Comment: Reading your answer again I think I may have misunderstood what you said. To be clear, I load the XML into the client's Flash Player, in this case, every time the application is loaded. When you said DOM object -- I assumed you meant that every time the web application is loaded, I would store the XML via Javascript into e.g. a hidden form value or the like. What, actually, did you mean? Thanks!

Comment: You hadn't mentioned anything about Flash, but I assumed that loading XML into any program means that it would have to be parsed and stored in a data structure in memory.  Usually that's a DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to resource management.  If you have the resources to run queries it is a better road because your data is "live" vs. having an XML file that is cached and then parsing it.  If you are worried about performance unless you are querying tens of millions of rows of data I wouldn't be too concerned.  We have a box with about 60+ clients that constantly run queries all day and the box can actually perform quite well with everything running.  XML parsing can be more stressful to the server than a query most of the time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not worried about performance in the sense of e.g. scalability, but rather interested by the fact that a full text search of 5 fields takes a few seconds in a db query against SQLite, versus being "instant" with the loaded XML approach. Can you possibly expand on your "more stressful to the server" point?

Comment: When parsing XML you are usually using more resources to parse the XML than what it would take to query and return a row of data.  Obviously it depends on the length of data in the XML, what you have now might be instant but when that data crawls into a bigger monster you will notice XML will take longer to parse than SQL returns it.  If you really want to optimize the application and keep live data and you are using PHP as your backend take a look at the features of Zend Framework.http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html